# Memcache not setting values ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached

I have installed memcache on our local dev server and is working correctly. I can telnet from my machine and from the server :)

I have configured my app to use the service on the dev machine however when attempting to add to cache the values are never set!! Here is my config. Please help.

Also this seems to work when changing the protocol to text instead of Binary, however I can't use text because I am caching domain objects which aren't serializable.

Thanks

```
<enyim.com>
<memcached protocol="Binary">
  <servers>
    <add address="*********" port="11211" />
  </servers>
  <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="20" connectionTimeout="00:00:10" deadTimeout="00:00:10" />
  <locator type="Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultNodeLocator, Enyim.Caching" />
  <keyTransformer type="Enyim.Caching.Memcached.SHA1KeyTransformer, Enyim.Caching" />
</memcached></enyim.com>
```

Line that is always false.

```
bool setCache = _client.Store(StoreMode.Set, key, data, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheTime));
```

Comment: Is the memcached service running? Do you get any exceptions when attempting to connect to memcached?

Comment: Yes the server is running and no errors when connecting to memcache. This is the line that is always false: bool setCache = _client.Store(StoreMode.Set, key, data, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheTime));

Comment: I am getting closer apparently I need to mark all classes as serializable?? Is there any way around this?